# Java FileInputStream read character not accurate？？？？

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Hello，I am a graduate student of computer science in China and I have a simple problem don't know why,please reply me , thank you.
FileInputStream Problem，use FileInputStream  to read file，and show that. The txt include two lines，and all have 15 characters，but the result as follows:

```
=(-
=1-
=,-
=2-
=,-
=1-
=0-
=)-
-
=
-
=(-
=1-
=,-
=4-
=,-
=5-
=)-
17
```

I don't konw why shown me that ''= - ="(the 11-13 lines of result)，and the length should 15 why 17？？？？

```
//Code and Txt
```

First， a ReadFile.java as follows：

```
package cn.bin;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class BestWayMP {
    private static final String FilePath="bestWayMP.txt";


    /**
     * 读取文件内容
     * @return 拼接的字符串
     * @throws IOException IO异常
     */
    public String LoadingFiles() throws IOException {
        File file=new File(FilePath);
        StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();
        if(file!=null&&file.isFile()){
            FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
            fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
            byte r[]=new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len=fileInputStream.read(r))!=-1){
                String str=new String(r,0,len,"utf-8");
               buf.append(str.trim());
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("文件不存在");
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String  args[]){
        try {
            String str=new BestWayMP().LoadingFiles();
            for(int x=0;x<str.length();x++){
                System.out.println("="+str.charAt(x)+"-");
            }
            System.out.println(str.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Second，the content of bestWayMP.txt as follows（encoding is utf-8）：

```
(1,2,10)
(1,4,5)
```

Comment: There is an line terminator at the end of each line. (Either a CR (carriage return) character or a LF (line feed) character.)  They are "non-printing" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file has a line separator which is parsed that is added to your StringBuffer and is processed in your main function as the other characters are. When you read your file into the program, you will get

`buf = (1,2,10)\r\n(1,4,5)`.

You can either not have line separators in your text file or you can prevent it from being added into your StringBuffer.

Check out this [article](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-replace-line-breaks-new-lines-windows-mac-linux.html)  to see how to deal with them